# Unable to send a post requests OKEX Invalid Signature

Tags: python, exchange-server

This is the code, i hid the api key secret and passphrase.
The problem is that now it give me 'cannot be an empty body' if i change in the post requests json with data = body it gives me invalid sign. Why?
Thanks in advance.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

```
import hmac
import base64
import requests
import json
BASE_URL = "https://www.okex.com"
def get_time():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    t = now.isoformat("T", "milliseconds")
    return t + "Z"

# signature
def signature(timestamp, method, request_path, body,secret_key):
    if str(body) == '{}' or str(body) == 'None':
        body = ''
    message = str(timestamp) + str.upper(method) + request_path + str(body)
    mac = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
    d = mac.digest()
    return base64.b64encode(d)
def get_header():
    body= {}
    request= 'GET'
    endpoint= '/api/v5/account/positions'
    header = dict()
    header['CONTENT-TYPE'] = 'application/json'
    header['OK-ACCESS-KEY'] = okex_key
    header['OK-ACCESS-SIGN'] = signature(get_time(), request, endpoint , body, okex_secret)
    header['OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = str(get_time())
    header['OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'] = okex_pass
    header['x-simulated-trading'] = b'1'
    return header
def post_header(body):

    request = 'POST'
    endpoint = '/api/v5/trade/order'
    header = dict()
    body = json.dumps(body)
    print(body)
    header['CONTENT-TYPE'] = 'application/json'
    header['OK-ACCESS-KEY'] = okex_key
    current_time=get_time()
    header['OK-ACCESS-SIGN'] = signature(current_time, request, endpoint , body, okex_secret)
    header['OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP']=str(current_time)
    header['OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'] = okex_pass
    header['x-simulated-trading'] = b'1'
    return header

def place_market_order(body):
    url_ = 'https://www.okex.com/api/v5/trade/order'

    body = json.dumps(body)
    header = post_header(body)
    print(header)
    print(body)
    response = requests.post(url_ ,json=body,headers=header)

    return response.json()

url = "https://www.okex.com"
body = {"instId": "BTC-USDT-SWAP",
            "tdMode": "cross",
            "posSide" :"long",
            "side": "buy",
            "ordType": "market",
            "sz": "1"
            }
print(str(place_market_order(body)))
```

Comment: Hey Alessio.  Welcome to the forum.  It would be helpful for others if you perhaps post the stack trace of the error you receive and also perhaps what you have already tried to resolve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

> body = json.dumps(body)

> header = post_header(body)

> response = requests.post(url_ ,json=body,headers=header)

The problem seems in "json=body", for its name's sake, json should be an object, not a string as in your code. This is how I made it work, passing an dict obj to json.